# set date as sheet name in Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to rename a newly created sheet with yesterday's date, and in some cases with the date 14 days ago. Here's what I've got so far.

I found this snippet here on Stackoverflow and modified it a little to suit my purpose. However, this produces the sheet to be named with today's date.

```
// previous lines have been left out
// set sheet name to yesterday's date

var eet = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
var sheets = ss.getSheets();
var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), eet, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
//this returns today's date (need yesterday's date, or date from 14 days ago)

sheets[1].setName(date);  // Rename second sheet
```

I hope you guys can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for yesterday's date.  It is subtracting 1 fro the current date

```
var testDate = new Date();
var secondDate = new Date();
secondDate.setDate(testDate.getDate()-1);
var dateString = Utilities.formatDate(secondDate, eet, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

Note that I did not check your setting of the date string.  I did rename the variable to avoid the reserved "Date" but it may not be necessary.

Comment: Thanks Karl! copied this into my code and modified the code around this and now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the names of the sheets before the execution.

[image]

Here are the names of the sheets after the execution.

[image]

Here's the code:

```
function changeSheetNamesWithDates() {

   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ENTER_SPREADSHEET_NAME");
   var sheets = ss.getSheets();

   var count = 0;
   for (var row in sheets) {

       var startDate = new Date();
           startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() - count);
       var dateString = Utilities.formatDate(startDate, "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd");

           sheets[row].setName("Sheet " + dateString);
           count++;
   }
}
```

If you want it purely dates only then remove the word "Sheet " from `.setName`:

```
 sheets[row].setName(dateString);
```